# How to calculate the difference of a list of various by key?

Tags: r, data.table, key, grouping

I have a data.table with key and about 1000 rows, two of which are set to key. I would like to create a new variable named **difference** that contains difference of each numeric rows which were grouped by key.

For example, the simple data is: ID and Act are set to as key

```
    ID  ValueDate Act Volume
    1 2015-01-01 EUR     21
    1 2015-02-01 EUR     22
    1 2015-01-01 MAD     12
    1 2015-02-01 MAD     11
    2 2015-01-01 EUR      5
    2 2015-02-01 EUR      7
    3 2015-01-01 EUR      4
    3 2015-02-01 EUR      2
    3 2015-03-01 EUR      6
```

What I would like to have is: adding a new column to calculate the difference between two rows(order by Time) for each group, note that for the first row of each group , the value of difference is 0.

```
    ID  ValueDate Act Volume Difference
    1 2015-01-01 EUR     21    0
    1 2015-02-01 EUR     22    1
    1 2015-01-01 MAD     12    0
    1 2015-02-01 MAD     11   -1
    2 2015-01-01 EUR      5    0
    2 2015-02-01 EUR      7    2
    3 2015-01-01 EUR      4    0
    3 2015-02-01 EUR      2   -2
    3 2015-03-01 EUR      6    4
```

Here is a code to generate test data:

```
    dd <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), 
                     ValueDate = c("2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-01-01","2015-02-01", "2015-01-01","2015-02-01","2015-01-01","2015-02-01","2015-03-01"),
                     Act = c("EUR","EUR","MAD","MAD","EUR","EUR","EUR","EUR","EUR"),
                     Volume=c(21,22,12,11,5,7,4,2,6))
```

set key for the table:

```
    setkey(dd, ID, Act)
```

to view the data:

```
    > dd
       ID  ValueDate Act Volume
    1  1 2015-01-01 EUR     21
    2  1 2015-02-01 EUR     22
    3  1 2015-01-01 MAD     12
    4  1 2015-02-01 MAD     11
    5  2 2015-01-01 EUR      5
    6  2 2015-02-01 EUR      7
    7  3 2015-01-01 EUR      4
    8  3 2015-02-01 EUR      2
    9  3 2015-03-01 EUR      6
```

so , can we use the function of aggregate to calculate the difference? or the method of .SD for "subset of data, but I don't know how to do the calculation of difference between two rows by group,note that for some groups, the number of rows might be different as well, but i have tried before is using the **for(i in 0:x)** to re-calculate the difference, but I don't think it could be a good method :(

Comment: Are there always going to be exactly two records?  What do you want to have happen if their aren't?

Comment: actually not always going to be two records, this is just a simple case, some of the groups have more records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want explicitly use your key, you could pass a `key`call to the `by` argument

```
dd[, Difference := c(0L, diff(Volume)), by = key(dd)]
dd
#    ID  ValueDate Act Volume Difference
# 1:  1 2015-01-01 EUR     21          0
# 2:  1 2015-02-01 EUR     22          1
# 3:  1 2015-01-01 MAD     12          0
# 4:  1 2015-02-01 MAD     11         -1
# 5:  2 2015-01-01 EUR      5          0
# 6:  2 2015-02-01 EUR      7          2
# 7:  3 2015-01-01 EUR      4          0
# 8:  3 2015-02-01 EUR      2         -2
# 9:  3 2015-03-01 EUR      6          4
```

Or using `data.table` v 1.9.6+ you could also utilize the `shift` function

```
dd[, Difference := Volume - shift(Volume, fill = Volume[1L]), by = key(dd)]
```

Comment: Hi, @David Arenburg, thanks for your answer, i tried this before, but there was error , said                                                                                      Error in `[.data.frame`(dd, , `:=`(Difference, c(0L, diff(Volume))), by = key(dd)) : 
  unused argument (by = key(dd))

Comment: You said `dd` is a data.table already. Didn't you run `setkey(setDT(dd), ID, Act)` before that?

Comment: oh!! i found the my mistake, you are right, i just generated the data with a wrong format, and now , it works great! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'ID', 'Act', we create the 'Difference' column as the difference of 'Volume' and `lag` of that column.

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>%
  group_by(ID, Act) %>%
  mutate(Difference = Volume-lag(Volume))
```

EDIT: As mentioned by @DavidArenburg, replacing `lag(Volume)` by `lag(Volume, default = Volume[1L])` will give 0 instead of NA for the first element in each group.

---

Or with `ave` from `base R`, we can do the `diff` and concatenate with `0` so that the lengths are the same.  The `diff` returns a vector with length one less than the length of the original vector.

```
with(dd, ave(Volume, ID, Act, FUN= function(x) c(0, diff(x)))
```

Comment: You could probably use `lag(Volume, default = Volume[1L])` in order to match OP output.

Comment: @akrun, thanks for your sharing !! i tried the method you said, it works great!!

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I have hard time working that thing correct in windows 7.  That was the one I tried first. `Error: expecting a single value`

Comment: I'm using windows 7 too. Maybe you need to update package version.